# How to assign a value to a bytes variable?

Tags: solidity, bytes

The function `keccak256 ()` takes a bytes variable. You can't pass it bytes3 or byte []; it has to be of type *bytes*.

How do you set that to a specific value?

Here are some things I've tried, and the error messages I got.

```
bytes memory a = 0x05;
Error: Type int_const 5 is not implicitly convertible to expected type bytes memory.

bytes memory b = bytes (0x05);
Error: Explicit type conversion not allowed from "int_const 5" to "bytes memory".

bytes1 c = 0x05;
bytes memory d = c;
Error: Type bytes1 is not implicitly convertible to expected type bytes memory.

bytes memory e = bytes (c);
Error: Explicit type conversion not allowed from "bytes1" to "bytes memory".
```

Is it even possible to create a variable of type bytes and set it to specific hex bytes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bytes` is essentially an array or reference type and you are trying to assign a primitive value to an array.

You can use assembly to store any value in `bytes` array.

```
function test() public pure returns (uint256 returnValue) {
    bytes memory b = new bytes(32);
    
    assembly {
        mstore(add(b, 32), 5)
        returnValue := mload(add(b, 32))
    }
}
```

In the above code we initialize a `bytes` array with length 32. It can store an integer of size 256 bits in the 32 bytes it has. If we look at the content of variable `b` in memory, it will return 32 and that is the length of the array. The integer value is stored in the next 32 bytes.

Without using assembly you can only assign values to `bytes` array byte by byte using the index of the array. Like so,

```
bytes memory b = new bytes(1)
b[0] = 0x05;
```

Here, you have the bytes array with length 1 which is assigned a single byte value. And reading the content of `b` using `mload(b)` will return 1 and that is the length of array `b` here.

My answer is about why `bytes` assigning is not working. For the `keccak` hashing part of your question you can refer to Abhishek's answer.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution to this can be .. 
Using `keccak256(abi.encodePacked(args))`

This should work.